# Strip in Python

Tags: python, strip

I have a question regarding `strip()` in Python. I am trying to strip a semi-colon from a string, I know how to do this when the semi-colon is at the end of the string, but how would I do it if it is not the last element, but say the second to last element.

eg:

```
1;2;3;4;\n
```

I would like to strip that last semi-colon.

Comment: What if there are multiple consecutive semicolons at the end? Strip all or just one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strip the other characters as well.

```
>>> '1;2;3;4;\n'.strip('\n;')
'1;2;3;4'
```

Comment: How would I strip it without stripping the newline?

Comment: You can't; stripping *only* removes from the ends. If you need the newline then add it back after.

Comment: No biggy, but you might want to use `rstrip` instead

Comment: My +1 to wim. You should use `rstrip` in the case. The reason is that the `strip` argument is interpreted as a set of characters that should be stripped (i.e. all of them -- the order is not important). If the semicolon were used at the beginning (i.e. empty first element) the `strip` would remove also the first semicolon.

Comment: see my answer if you could have unspecified number of white spaces after last ";" like '1;2;3;4; \t\n'

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> "".join("1;2;3;4;\n".rpartition(";")[::2])
'1;2;3;4\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

how about replace?

```
string1='1;2;3;4;\n'
string2=string1.replace(";\n","\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> string = "1;2;3;4;\n"
>>> string.strip().strip(";")
"1;2;3;4"
```

This will first strip any leading or trailing white space, and then remove any leading or trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def remove_last(string):
    index = string.rfind(';')
    if index == -1:
        # Semi-colon doesn't exist
        return string
    return string[:index] + string[index+1:]
```

This should be able to remove the last semicolon of the line, regardless of what characters come after it.

```
>>> remove_last('Test')
'Test'
>>> remove_last('Test;abc')
'Testabc'
>>> remove_last(';test;abc;foobar;\n')
';test;abc;foobar\n'
>>> remove_last(';asdf;asdf;asdf;asdf')
';asdf;asdf;asdfasdf'
```

The other answers provided are probably faster since they're tailored to your specific example, but this one is a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r';(\W*$)', r'\1', '1;2;3;4;\n') -> '1;2;3;4\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string with semi colon and then join the non-empty parts back again using ; as separator

```
parts = '1;2;3;4;\n'.split(';')
non_empty_parts = []
for s in parts:
    if s.strip() != "": non_empty_parts.append(s.strip())
print "".join(non_empty_parts, ';')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the strip function this is one method:
Using slice notation, you can limit the strip() function's scope to one part of the string and append the "\n" on at the end:

```
# create a var for later
str = "1;2;3;4;\n"
# format and assign to newstr
newstr = str[:8].strip(';') + str[8:]
```

Using the rfind() method(similar to Micheal0x2a's solution) you can make the statement applicable to many strings:

```
# create a var for later
str = "1;2;3;4;\n"
# format and assign to newstr
newstr = str[:str.rfind(';') + 1 ].strip(';') + str[str.rfind(';') + 1:]
```