# String function to strip the last comma

Tags: python

Input

```
str = 'test1,test2,test3,'
```

Ouput

```
str = 'test1,test2,test3'
```

Requirement to strip the last occurence of ','

Comment: Searching the Python docs for 'strip' didn't find you anything?

Comment: A search in stack would give many similar threads, here is [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557794/strip-in-python)

Comment: stupid downvotes. This was useful question for me.

Answer (score 119):

Just use [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip).

```
result = your_string.rstrip(',')
```

Comment: to me it strips all commas. why? I even tried strip() but the same occurs:
for i in range(str1,str2):
 print(i,','.strip(','),end='')

Comment: use lstrip() for leading commas

Comment: By the way, if you'd like to remove any combination of trailing commas and whitespaces (which was my requirement), just add a whitespace along with comma: 
result = your_string.rstrip(', ')

Comment: How can i rstrip comma and trailing space together if any?

Answer (score 11):

```
str = 'test1,test2,test3,'
str[:-1] # 'test1,test2,test3'
```

Comment: This references the string without the last character - even if it is not a comma.  The `rstrip()` solution is more fault tolerant.

Answer (score 2):

**The question is very old but tries to give the better answer**

```
str = 'test1,test2,test3,'
```

It will check the last character, if the last character is a comma it will remove otherwise will return the original string.

```
result = str[:-1] if str[-1]==',' else str
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is little bit over work for something like that. I think this statement will help you.

```
str = 'test1,test2,test3,'    
result = ','.join([s for s in str.split(',') if s]) # 'test1,test2,test3'
```

Comment: I ended up with exactly that to solve ```str= 'test1,test2,test3,,,,,``` which showed up after reading a CSV file with some "not-quite-blank" cells at the end of some rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to remove the last comma (also as the last character?) you can do this via the function `removesuffix()`

Here is an example:

```py
>>>'hello,'.removesuffix(',')
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have to consider the worst case also.

The worst case is,

```
str= 'test1,test2,test3, ,,,, '
```

for above code, please use following code,

```
result = ','.join([s.strip() for s in str.split(',') if s.strip()!=''])
```

It will work/remove the prefix 'comma' also. For example,

```
str= ' , ,test1,test2,test3, ,,,, '
```